# How to ignore the catch clause of a promise in Jest test coverage?

Tags: jestjs, istanbul

In my unit tests I have one case where I get a promise from a browser API (IndexedDB) and added a catch clause to handle any error condition. For obvious reasons I cannot trigger the promise to fail in my tests. After all this is internal to the browser.

That's why I want to ignore the catch clause for code coverage. How can I do that?

Note: for try/catch blocks it is possible to write the istanbul ignore hint like this:

```js
try {
...
} catch(reason) /* istanbul ignore next */ {
...
}
```

See also https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/issues/559.

However this doesn't work with a promise.

Comment: What about writing a test case for the failure? That way the rejection will be tested to ensure you code works as expected, and you will get the code coverage you want.

Comment: I explained, why this is not possible.  An error can only occur when something in the API is wrong, which I cannot simulate in the tests. And I don't want to test the API validity, but that of my own code.

Comment: Just for clarity, you do not need to test the API itself, just mock the response in your test, which will then cause the error for your catch routine to ensure your code can handle the error should the API cause it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The place to add the ignore hint is directly before the closure in the catch clause:

```js
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(() => {
     ...
}).catch(/* istanbul ignore next */(reason) => {
    ...
});
```